# WebStorm - prevent search window from closing

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am using WebStorm. Every time I open the search window (of WebStorm) it is closed when I switch between the window/ tabs of the computer.

How can I prevent that and keep the window open when I get back to WebStorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "search window" you mean the "Find in Path" functionality which got a new design in 2017.1...

When switching **between the apps** -- it's a bug in 2017.1 -- it's [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168620) and should be available in **2017.1.1**

---

If the question is about "it closes when clicking outside of new search popup (e.g. in the code)" then please follow [IDEA-168640](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168640) ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

**P.S.** You may revert to the old style dialog if you so desire:

`-Dide.find.as.popup=false` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options will restore the original dialog.

Comment: Thanks, but if it will available at 2017.1.1, I assume it's already updated. and still I don't see the fix. 

About the flag inside the VM options -  it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Moris 1) What is exact IDE build you are using (`Help | About`). Ticket says "Fixed" .. so I'm expecting it to be available in 2017.1.1... 2) You may need to restart IDE if you are doing via `Edit Custom VM Options` (not 100% sure on that though -- never used it this way myself). I'm using `Registry...` action (you may use `Help | Find Action...` to find it) and it works straight away.

Comment: @LazyOne please don't suggest the users to do it via the Registry, we prefer not to promote this feature for the end users since they may trigger other options in that dialog they may find interesting and then start to report weird issues to support.

Comment: @CrazyCoder OK.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I updates the version recently and it was fixed. i guess it was kinda of bug.

Answer (score 0):

clicking on the "Pin" icon in the upper right helped me.

Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000138864/comments/5995088437906